# Does lazy loading work on externally hosted images?

Tags: wordpress, images

I will be using picasa or flickr for hosting images on my wordpress blog . And I have installed a image lazy loading plugin . Will lazy loading work for images hosted on picasa/flickr ?

Comment: What is the plug in name?

Comment: BJ Lazy Load https://wordpress.org/plugins/bj-lazy-load/ . I am using this plugin but does the concept of lazy loading work on externally hosted images ?

Comment: There's no reason why (the concept of) "lazy loading" can't work with externally hosted images. From the client's perspective there's really no difference in where the image is hosted. However, there could be issues in the way images are _pulled in_ from picasa/flickr and the order in which the page is generated? (Although _I think_ "BJ Lazy Load" can handle this OK.)

Comment: I don't see why you need lazy loading for images that are hosted externally since it doesn't affect the performance of your website at all.

Comment: @questionoverflow is that a joke I'm not getting? Displaying images from any source affects the performance of the page.

Comment: @renuka Why don't you just try it and see? What exactly are you expecting from this question?

Comment: Lazy loading will work as you expect.

Comment: @Renuka to answer your question in short. Yes. What Question overflow is hinting to is that since the images are not being served from your domain, their transfer will start in parallel while your theme files are being downloaded and will not slow the page rendering process.

Comment: Isn't this considered hotlinking? I've seen a similar question like this, but using imgur as an image CDN instead, like Stack Exchange do to store images from the site, but like they have permission for this. Does picasa or flickr have any policies against this?

Answer (score 1):

yes, but since these external images come from a 3rd part domain you need to make sure they are not blocking them via some method of cors or hotlink protection.

also add dns prefetch meta for domains you will be pulling from.